# Change filesystem encoding to UTF-8 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, utf-8

How to find out what charset encoding is used by current file system and how to change it to UTF-8?

**EDIT:**

Here is the output of mount:

```
/dev/sdb6 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
/proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
varrun on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
varlock on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
lrm on /lib/modules/2.6.27-11-generic/volatile type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Here is the output of "cat /etc/fstab"

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# /dev/sdb7
UUID=50d660f1-1948-41e1-96af-3cb9bca338dd /               ext3    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       0
# /dev/sdb8
UUID=efaee412-8e29-4f65-927d-f57252451088 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, the encoding of file names is not set at the filesystem level, but rather in the user environment. Check the output of `locale` and look at the stuff after the dot — for example, in my case `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, so the file names in my environment are interpreted as UTF-8. This is the default setting in Ubuntu.

The [answer from Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/questions/87055/change-filesystem-encoding-to-utf-8-in-ubuntu/87081#87081) is relevant for special filesystem types that require translation, and I am not attempting to get into this issue because your outputs of `mount` and `cat /etc/fstab` show this is not your case.

Comment: system locale is already en_US.UTF-8

Comment: I don't think this is true. My LANG-en_US.UTF8 but Ubuntu creates files as us_ascii. Ubuntu doesn't seem to do anything with encoding file system level. Unfortuantely

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what filesystem, however you can look at the output of `mount` which on one of my systems currently shows a iso9660 filesystem and a couple of vfat ones that are utf8. You can also look at the contents of `/etc/fstab` which is where you'd set them or they are already set. See `man mount` which shows that NTFS and jfs are two more that have that option.

Comment: @Dennis, I posted the output of mount and "cat /etc/fstab". It looks like there is no charset encoding information there.

Comment: You still don't say which filesystem/device or what specific problem you're trying to solve. As **Amir** said, you're apparently not using one of the filesystems I mentioned and you say `locale` is already correct. What is the issue?

Comment: @Dennis, you said your mount output shows you have a iso9660 filesystem. I have posted my mount output. I didn't see anything related to "filesystem" you mentioned in the output. Could you please help me figure it out?

Comment: The filesystem is what's listed after the word "type" in the output of `mount` or under the "type" column in `/etc/fstab`. In the output you show, "ext3" is an example. The iso9660 filesystem refers to a CD-ROM. What specifically is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses UTF-8 encoding by default and it seems you haven't changed it. You could have file names with a different encoding. In that case, you could use [convmv](http://j3e.de/linux/convmv/) to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can't really.

There are 2 things, the encoding of the filenames, and the encoding of the data in the files. In both cases the filesystem will *just* store the raw bytes. It's up the user to make sure they are the encoding the user wants.